# Scala Universal Serializer PlayFramework

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I want to make universal JSON Serializer of different my own list types(i.e. Group, GroupView, GroupItemsView). So, I define all three Json.Format

```
  implicit val groupsFormat = Json.format[Group]
  implicit val groupsViewFormat = Json.format[GroupView]
  implicit val groupsItemsViewFormat = Json.format[GroupItemsView]
```

My function that should serialize different list items:

```
  def groupViewToJson(entityList: List[Any]): JsValue = {
    val jsonList = Json.toJson(
      entityList.map( m => Json.toJson(m))
    )
    jsonList
  }
```

It only works when for for the entityList I define particular List Type. It doesn't want to work with Any type. The error as follows:

```
No Json serializer found for type Any. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
```

How to make PlayFramework Scala JSON Serializer to work with my type universally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `implicits` need to be resolved at compile time. Thus, your function needs to provide the right Writes implicit to the function during compilation. You can do that by using type parameter and accepting an implicit:

```
def groupViewToJson[T](entityList: List[T])(implicit writer:Writes[T]): JsValue = {
    val jsonList = Json.toJson(
      entityList.map( m => Json.toJson(m))
    )
    jsonList
  }
```

And when calling `groupViewToJson`, the implicit needs to be in scope. A complete example would be:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
case class Group(name:String)
case class GroupView(name:String, group: Group)

implicit val groupsFormat = Json.format[Group]
implicit val groupsViewFormat = Json.format[GroupView]
//implicit val groupsItemsViewFormat = Json.format[GroupItemsView]


def groupViewToJson[T](entityList: List[T])(implicit writer:Writes[T]): JsValue = {
    val jsonList = Json.toJson(
      entityList.map( m => Json.toJson(m))
    )
    jsonList
  }

scala> val group = Group("MyGroup")
group: Group = Group(MyGroup)

scala> val groupView = GroupView("MyGroupView", group)
groupView: GroupView = GroupView(MyGroupView,Group(MyGroup))

scala> groupViewToJson(groupView :: Nil)
res4: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = [{"name":"MyGroupView","group":{"name":"MyGroup"}}]
```

Comment: Thanks it solves my problem! I completely forgot about type parameterization.

Comment: Also, please note that Json already provides a writer for Lists, given that you have the writer for the case class, so unless you plan on adding more functionality to your groupViewToJson function, you can use it instead.